# INSERT INTO (SELECT * FROM ...) ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to find a solution for a generic SQL query.
The query looks like this right now:

```
INSERT INTO %s (SELECT * FROM %s)" % (table_name, table_name_tmp)
```

I want to add an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option for this query. But because of the "SELECT *" I have not managed to find a good solution yet.
How would you do it?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using MariaDB

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/

Comment: @CarlosSR Thank you, but my problem is that the values won't always be the same so I can't update a certain column.

Answer (score 0):

I've now found the query command: "IGNORE" to be of decent use in this case.

Hence my code would look like this and works moderately satisfactorily:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO %s (SELECT * FROM %s)" % (table_name, table_name_tmp)
```

A con is that this will render my code to never give errors for this Insert.